# Rails 3.0 migration link_to :remote=>true Ajax + JQuery ujs not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I've been migrating from Rails 2.3.14 to Rails 3.0.20 and I'm at a loss why I cant get Ajax calls to work through a link_to with :remote=>true.

Gemfile

```
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 1.0.19"
```

Command line:

```
    rails generate jquery:install --ui
      remove  public/javascripts/prototype.js
      remove  public/javascripts/effects.js
      remove  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
      remove  public/javascripts/controls.js
     copying  jQuery (1.7.1)
   identical  public/javascripts/jquery.js
   identical  public/javascripts/jquery.min.js
     copying  jQuery UI (1.8.16)
   identical  public/javascripts/jquery-ui.js
   identical  public/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js
     copying  jQuery UJS adapter (822920)
      remove  public/javascripts/rails.js
   identical  public/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js
```

In head:

```
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

Which resulted in:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="qH17FbbfwQNFTHWte&#47;CBYopzfEvf5gnHxGEUdDBfV+Y="/>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1381981377" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.js?1381981377" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/jquery_ujs.js?1381981377" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/application.js?1381984319" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Link tag that wont work:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("review-icon2_16x16.png", :border=>0),
                      {:controller=>"sponjson", :action=>"review", :id=>"#{sponsor.id}"},
                      {:remote=>true, :id=>"review_spon_id_#{sponsor.id}", :alt=>"Flag for Review", :title=>"Flag for Review", :confirm => "Review ...  Are you sure?" }
                      %><br/>
```

EDIT.  Add link tag expanded HTML:

```
<a href="/sponjson/review/77" alt="Flag for Review" data-confirm="Review .. Are you sure?" data-remote="true" id="review_spon_id_77" title="Flag for Review"><img alt="Review-icon2_16x16" border="0" src="/images/review-icon2_16x16.png?1338407096" /></a>
```

With supporting UJS:

```
<%=  raw("<script type='text/javascript'>
              $('#review_spon_id_#{sponsor.id}').bind('ajax:before', function(evt, status, data, xhr) {
                  beforeAjaxStatus('sstatus_#{sponsor.id}')
              });
              $('#review_spon_id_#{sponsor.id}').bind('ajax:complete', function(evt, status, data, xhr) {
                  completeAjaxStatusReview('sstatus_#{sponsor.id}')
              });
        </script>" )%>
```

THE PROBLEM: When I click on the link, it is NOT an AJAX request. Calls the controller just fine with this response:

```
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { (head :ok) }
      format.js { (head :ok) }
      format.xml  { (head :ok) }
    end
```

EDIT: with routes:

```
/sponjson/review/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"sponsors", :action=>"review"}     
/sponjson/:id(.:format) {:controller=>"sponsors", :action=>"update"}   
/:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was missing "data-type"=>"json".  This made the controller be able to detect it as a json call (with appropriate content-type) and therefore respond accordingly:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("review-icon2_16x16.png", :border=>0),
                      {:controller=>"sponjson", :action=>"review", :id=>"#{sponsor.id}"},
                      {:remote=>true, "data-type"=>"json", :id=>"review_spon_id_#{sponsor.id}", :alt=>"Flag for Review", :title=>"Flag for Review", :confirm => "Review ...  Are you sure?" }
                      %><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attaching your JS events to the data-id rather than the link's id. You're also setting a border on the image, which isn't supported (supported params listed [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)).

Try changing your link to the following:

```
<%= link_to review_sponjson(sponsor), remote: true, confirm: "Are you sure?", id: "review_spon_id_#{sponsor.id}" do %>
  <%= image_tag("review-icon2_16x16.png", alt: "Flag for Review") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That didn't work verbatim.   The :confirm: syntax was an issue so I changed that to 'confirm: "Are you sure?"' .. but then the resulting HTML was:  <a href="/sponjson/review/review_spon_id_77?confirm=Are+you+sure%3F&amp;remote=true">
              <img alt="Flag for Review" src="/images/review-icon2_16x16.png?1338407096" />
          </a><br/>

Comment: Can you clarify how to attach the events to the link's ID instead of the data-id?  Not sure I can tell the difference.  The link_to rendered (the original version I had)  into:  <a href="/sponjson/review/77" alt="Flag for Review" data-confirm="Review .. Are you sure?" data-remote="true" id="review_spon_id_77" title="Flag for Review"><img alt="Review-icon2_16x16" border="0" src="/images/review-icon2_16x16.png?1338407096" /></a><br/>

Comment: Could you run `rake routes` and update your question real quick? Specifying the controller, action, and id is a little hacky and probably shouldn't be required.

Comment: I have verified it is indeed getting to the correct controller/action.   Did notice that the accept header does not specify json but in the past, when HTML is sent back, the Ajax call just attempts to intepret the HTML which I'd be happy with .. since I know its an Ajax call.    Here are the pertinant routes:                     /sponjson/review/:id(.:format)       {:controller=>"sponsors", :action=>"review"}
                          /sponjson/:id(.:format)                        {:controller=>"sponsors", :action=>"update"}        /:controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)